# how to make a query using textarea parameters using PHP

Tags: php, textarea

first, sorry for english!

I'm trying to make a query where I pass the parameters using textarea and my code just works if i write one line in my textarea.

My code:

```html
//taking the textarea value
    $text = $_POST['coment'];

$teste = $text = str_replace("\n",",",$text);



$sql = "SELECT CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,DATA_EXPIRACAO from senha where CODIGO_VENDEDOR IN ('" . $teste . "')";

$results = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { ?>
 <table>
 <td style="padding:5px"> <?php echo $row["CODIGO_VENDEDOR"];?></td>
 <td style="padding:5px"> <?php echo $row["NOME_VENDEDOR"];?></td>
 <td style="padding:5px"> <?php echo $row["SENHA_URA"];?></td>
 </table>
 
<?php }
?
```

Comment: `$teste` and `$test` - 2 different animals here. And who knows if `$_POST['coment']` has a value.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. You'll see an undefined variable notice.

Comment: sorry, miss the letter "e", the correct variable is: $teste

Comment: yeah well... posted code is taken "literally" and for "face value". If that's a typo, someone would've most likely posted an answer for it. If it's a typo, you need to fix it in your question.

Comment: okay, i corrected it

Comment: What is the actual runtime value of `$_POST['coment']`?  And of `$teste`?

Comment: $_POST['coment'] is the codes I want to search in mysql db... for exemple: 12345,jbcd1,887y1

Comment: I want search every single code in textarea in mysql db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable `$_POST['comment']` has something like this:

123,456,567... (comma separated values)

Then you need something like this:

```
$teste = explode(",", $_POST['coment']);
```

And then in the SQL put something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,DATA_EXPIRACAO 
        FROM senha 
        WHERE CODIGO_VENDEDOR IN ('" . implode("','", $teste) . "')";
```

Why your code is not working?

Well, you are receiving something like this "12345,jbcd1,887y1" and concatenate directly to SQL so you get something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,DATA_EXPIRACAO 
        FROM senha 
        WHERE CODIGO_VENDEDOR IN ('12345,jbcd1,887y1')";
```

As you can see the problem is that you need different values, so you need something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,DATA_EXPIRACAO 
        FROM senha 
        WHERE CODIGO_VENDEDOR IN ('12345','jbcd1','887y1')";
```

And this is what the above code does.

Comment: tks for your help but it didn't works..show just one record. Do you know why?

Comment: Print the result query and post it. If you execute this query on mysql client what is the result? what is the expected result?

Comment: If I execute the query in phpmyadmin it works only if I put quotation marks ("") on each ID. Ex: SELECT 
        CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,DATA_EXPIRACAO 
        FROM senha 
        WHERE CODIGO_VENDEDOR IN ('MAQ04','12345');

Comment: So, i think I need to find a way to put  quotation marks on each ID before do the Select, don't you think?

Comment: If i understand correctly this is the query result right? `SELECT CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,DATA_EXPIRACAO FROM senha WHERE CODIGO_VENDEDOR IN ('MAQ04','12345');` this query doesn't work? seems ok. Did you try my code? `sql = "SELECT 
        CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,DATA_EXPIRACAO 
        FROM senha 
        WHERE CODIGO_VENDEDOR IN ('" . implode("','", $teste) . "')";`

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was useful, mark as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query from:

```
$sql = "SELECT CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,DATA_EXPIRACAO from senha where CODIGO_VENDEDOR IN ('" . $teste . "')";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,DATA_EXPIRACAO from senha where CODIGO_VENDEDOR IN ('$teste')";
```

Comment: Both of the queries are correct, this is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

I could solve that using foreach. Like This:

```html
$teste = explode("\r\n",$_POST['comentario']);

foreach($teste as $teste2){
$sql = "SELECT 
        CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,
 DATA_EXPIRACAO 
        FROM senha 
        WHERE CODIGO_VENDEDOR = ('$teste2')";

$results = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { ?>
 <table>
 <td style="padding:5px"> <?php echo 
 $row["CODIGO_VENDEDOR"];?></td>
 <td style="padding:5px"> <?php echo 
 $row["NOME_VENDEDOR"];?></td>
 <td style="padding:5px"> <?php echo 
 $row["SENHA_URA"];?></td>
 </table>
 
<?php }}
?>
```

Comment: This way you will multiply your queries to the DBMS. You can remove the `(` from the query:

`SELECT 
        CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,
 DATA_EXPIRACAO 
        FROM senha 
        WHERE CODIGO_VENDEDOR = '$teste2'`